Xcode 3.2 Development Prevented by VMware Tools Installation Issues on Mac OS X Server 10.6
I need to develop on Xcode 3.2, and the only way was to create a VM with Mac OS X Server 10.6.
However, when I try to install VMware Tools, I get this error:
Unable to update run-time folder sharing status: VMware Tools are not running in the guest

I am using macOS 14.5 (Intel) and VMware Fusion Pro 13. The lack of features is infuriating; it takes too long to even use the VM without VMware Tools. I would greatly appreciate better graphics and the ability to share files or at least copy and paste.
Any advice would be welcomed!
Thanks!

Btw this question was taken down by (Dalija Prasnikar, President James K. Polk and Filburt) because it was not about programming or software development. If the stuff are slightly older does not mean I have to post this on cooking websites.
I think it fits in the category of software tools used by programmers.

For developers needing to work with Xcode 3.2 and the latest VMware, I found it to work perfectly fine with OS X 10.7 and Xcode 3.2.2. This setup operates seamlessly with VMware Fusion 13.0.2 and its tools on macOS Sonoma(Intel).
However, you might encounter an error when trying to install VMware Tools.pkg, or the installation might not start at all. To fix this, go to settings and navigate to CD/DVD (SATA). If the "Connect CD/DVD Drive" option is checked, eject VMware Tools from inside the VM. Then, choose the option "Choose a disc or disc image...". Multiple disc images will appear (e.g., Linux, Windows). Select the second Darwin image, which in my case was darwinPre15.iso. Ensure the "Connect CD/DVD Drive" option is checked, and then proceed to install the tools.
